Blind guy is fit with a machine that makes him see
I saw a movie back in the 80's about a blind guy who experiments with a sort of new scientific machine/sunglasses/viewer that allows him to see outlines of people.  In the beginning of the movie he gets beat up/mugged by a small gang of thugs and then at the end he can "see" them and ends up beating them up.  I believe it was a drama or possibly a love story of sorts.  
Somewhere in my head I believe he also lives in an apartment in like NYC next to some lady who plays the cello or something like that but i could be totally wrong about that part.
Anyone know the name of the movie?

Sounds like Blind Date from 1984 with Kirstie Alley.

A man goes blind when remembering his lost girlfriend, but the doctors can't find anything wrong with his eyes. They fit him with an experimental device which allows him to see with the aid of a computer interface and brain electrodes. Meanwhile, a taxi driver is taking young women up to their apartments, giving them gas, and performing a little fatal amateur surgery on them. Their paths inevitably converge, and the blind man must try to stop the psychopath.

He can only see people's outlines. Here's the trailer, where you can see the scenes where the hero is attacked by a gang and later gets back at them with his new ability:




yep thats it! awesome thanks so much!
